# String index out of range: -1

Tags: java

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int romantoint = 0;
        String input_symbolScanner = in.nextLine();
        in.close();
        for (int i = 0; i < input_symbolScanner.length(); i++) {
            char s = input_symbolScanner.charAt(i);
            switch (s) {
                case 'I':
                    romantoint = romantoint + 1;

                    break;
                case 'V':
                    romantoint = romantoint + 5;

                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("skip");

            }

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < input_symbolScanner.length(); i++) {
            char s = input_symbolScanner.charAt(i);
            if (input_symbolScanner.charAt(i) == 'V' && input_symbolScanner.charAt(i -1) == 'I') {
                
                romantoint = romantoint - 2;

            }
        }
        System.out.println(romantoint);
    }
}
```

При введение значений "VI" происходит ошибка:

```
***Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
        at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:47)
        at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:693)
        at leetcode.App.main(App.java:35)***
```

Comment: исправил, прошу прощения

Comment: Обозначь строку 35. Не пойму где ошибка

Comment: if (input_symbolScanner.charAt(i) == 'V' && input_symbolScanner.charAt(i -1) == 'I') {

Comment: Вы когда сюда `input_symbolScanner.charAt(i -1)` приходите с `i = 0`, то обращаетесь к -1 элементу массива, которого нет, т.к. первый элемент имеет индекс 0.

Comment: @Swad не подскажите, как это условие лучше применить? ибо что i-1, что i+1 я все равно буду выходить за длину введенной строки >_<. Была идея исполдьзовать прохождение через строку ( for), но тут уже не условие, а цикл (

Comment: Начните ваш цикл с `i = 1` тогда вы выходить за границы не будете, только убедитесь, что считано 2 и более символа. Ну это как вариант.

Comment: @Swad спасибо большо, swad, Вы уберегли мою жизнь!